# Blackberry touchscreen event clashing

Tags: blackberry, event-handling, touchscreen

I have

```
    if(eventCode == TouchEvent.DOWN)
    {
        //code
    }
    if(eventCode == TouchEvent.MOVE)
    {
        //code
    }
    if(eventCode == TouchEvent.UP)
    {
        //code
    }
    if(eventCode == TouchEvent.GESTURE)
    {
        if (gestureCode == TouchGesture.PINCH_END)
        {
           //code
        }
    }
```

The problem is that a Pinch, fires `DOWN -> GESTURE -> UP`

The Events DOWN MOVE UP are used for dragging the map around.

Where as Pinch is for zooming in/out.

How can I keep them separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `PINCH_BEGIN`. I set a global `myMode` variable that tells it its in pinch mode. So `MOVE` and `UP` Cannot fire.

And then on pinch up, reset the mode.

```
if(eventCode == TouchEvent.DOWN)
{
    mode = 1;
    //code
}
if(eventCode == TouchEvent.MOVE && mode == 1)
{
    //code
}
if(eventCode == TouchEvent.UP && mode == 1)
{
    mode = 0;
    //code
}
if(eventCode == TouchEvent.GESTURE)
{
    if (gestureCode == TouchGesture.PINCH_BEGIN)
   {
       mode = 2;
    }
    if (gestureCode == TouchGesture.PINCH_END)
    {
       mode = 0;
       //code

    }
}
```

This way for MOVE it runs :

`DOWN -> MOVE -> UP`

and pinch runs:

`DOWN -> DOWN -> PINCH_BEGIN -> PINCH_END`

(`PINCH_BEGIN` executes before `MOVE` is attempted to be called. And so is overriden by the new mode)